# Как сделать добивание корабля в морском бою на с++?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Доброго времени суток. Пишу сейчас консольный морской бой на С++ (можно даже сказать С поскольку без использования классов)ю Сделал расстановку кораблей, стрельбу за игрока, и стрельбу компьютеру. Но ломаю голову над алгоритмом добивания, то есть когда ИИ попал в корабль нужно, чтобы он продолжал стрелять в той же области. Единственное, что пришло это сохранять координаты в статическую переменную и потом циклом проверять что есть вокруг. Но идея сырая и не реализована. Хотелось бы узнать как вы решали данную проблему (код не обязательно, алгоритм подкиньте). Пишу в обычной процедурке.

Answer (score 1):

Впринципе вы все правильно решили: берете координаты поподания и пытаетесь понять в какую сторону развернут корабль - для этого сгодится и обычный рандом. Когдс же направление найдено, то стрелять до тех пор, пока корабль не затонет, либо пока не выйдет за пределы коробля и стрелять в противоположную сторону для затопления. Функции rand, do while и for в помощь

Answer (score 1):

Статическая переменная с координатами точки попадания (х,у). Рассмотрим точку не являющуюся концом поля. 
1 Проверяем (х+1,у):
- да - корабль расположен вдоль оси х, ставим соответствующий флаг. Долбим дальше пока не промахнемся, далее (х-1,у) и дальше пока не промах, после чего корабль затонул. Иначе
2 проверяем (х,у+1) все по аналогии с 1
Так же 
3 (х-1,у) 
4 (х,у-1)
Если нет, то корабль одинарный, затонул.
Для разнообразия можно произвести рандомизацию направлений поиска по некой переменной.
Так же следует учитывать конец поля
На сколько я понял архитектуру функция должна быть сквозная (без циклов) и исполняется во время хода компьютера, поэтому переходы внутри нее должны базироваться на статических флагах/переменных внутри нее.

Comment: Спасибо.Может ещё подскажите как заштриховать буферную область вокруг корабля

Comment: Да аналогичным образом. координаты каждой точки корабля надо запомнить. Варианта 2. 1 - если не страшно что одна и та же клетка (точка) будет заштрихована более одного раза: по очереди каждую координату корабля, проверять на конец поля и на сам корабль и заштриховывать если нет. 2 - немного сложнее определить расположение (верт/гор) в зависимости от этого и от того является ли точка концом или серединой штриховать если конец - 5 точек, если середина - 2 в соответствующих направлениях